# Display objects that belong to parent object dynamically in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I'm trying to create dropdown lists that are dynamic and based upon a selected parent object.

My models are Community, Lots, Homes, and Community Homes

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lots
  has_many :community_homes
  has_many :communities, through: :community_homes
end
------------------------------------------------------------------
class CommunityHome < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :community
  belongs_to :home
end
------------------------------------------------------------------
class Lot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :community
end
------------------------------------------------------------------
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :community_homes
  has_many :communities, through: :community_homes
end
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The form has a dropdown list of all the communities.  I need other dropdown lists to only display lots and homes that are associated with the selected community.

For example, one of my communities has 29 lots and 14 floor plans (homes).  When that community is selected I want those 29 lots and 14 homes to be the only objects in the dropdown list instead of all 198 lots and 45 homes.  Any help and/or a simple point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated...THANKS!

**<---------------------------  EDITED INFO  --------------------------->**

The form that I'm selecting the community, lot and home is a contract.  The Homes CRUD is separate from Communities and Contracts, then joined to Communities through the has_many through association.  Lots are created as belonging to Communities.

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :customer_name, :customer_phone_number, presence: true
  has_one :community
  has_one :lot
  has_one :home
end
```

---

Contract form

```
= simple_form_for @contract do |f|
  .community-select
    = f.collection_select( :community, Community.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => false } )
  %br
  .lot-select  
    = f.collection_select( :lot_number, Lot.all, :id, :number, {}, { :multiple => false } )
  %br
  .inputs
    = f.text_field :property_address, placeholder: "Property Address", class: "myform-control"
  %br
    = f.text_field :customer_name, placeholder: "Customer Name", class: "myform-control"
  %br
    = f.text_field :customer_phone_number, placeholder: "Customer Phone Number", class: "myform-control"
  %br
    = f.text_field :selection_date, placeholder: "Selection Date", class: "myform-control"
  %br
  .home-select
    = f.collection_select(:home, Home.all, :name, :name, {}, {:multiple => false } )
  %br
= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-success"
= link_to "Cancel", contracts_path, type: "button", class: "btn btn-danger"
```

---

I'm using the gem active_model_serializer for .json

Answer (score 0):

I would (as it already should be) make the value of the dropdown option the id of the `community`. Using JS add an event listener on that element and when it changes make an AJAX call to fetch the next piece of information using the selected *community's* `id`. Then in the response handler for the AJAX call populate the options.  This would be a good use case for any JS MV* framework such as backbone, ember, angular, etc.  You can then use a templating framework to generate the HTML that is to be inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up getting it working.  I got rid of active_model serializers gem and used JSON as is in Rails.
My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
...
  resources :communities, only: [:index, :show] do
    get :lots, on: :member
    get :homes, on: :member
  end
...
```

communities_controller.rb

```
class CommunitiesController < ApplicationController

  def lots
    @lots = @community.lots.available
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @lots }
    end
  end

  def homes
    @homes = @community.homes.all
      respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @homes }
    end
  end
```

contracts.js.coffee

```
  $("#contract_community_id").on "change", ->
    id = $(this).val()
    $.getJSON "/communities/#{id}/lots", (lot) ->
      $.each lot, (key, value) ->
        options = ""
        i = 0
        number = this.number
        while i < lot.length
          options += "<option value=\"" + lot[i].number + "\">" + lot[i].number + " "</option>"
          i++
        $("#contract_lot_number").html options
        return
      return
```